# How to find the last node from an html string with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have HTML string and want to get last closing tags.
e.g.

```
<h1>
   <p>some text</p>
<p>
  <ol>
   <li>item1Text</li>
  <ol>
</p>
</h1>
```

I want to insert a button after `item1Text`, thus I need to find 
last tags in the html string, in this case it is `</li><ol></p></h1>`

Question -> is there any easy and efficient way to get last tags in any give HTML string

Comment: This seems to just be a list of your requirements. Do you have any attempt to show us or a specific question to ask?

Comment: My question - is there any easy and efficient way to get `last` tags in any give HTML string.

Comment: You have not explained clearly what you mean by "last html tags".  Why isn't it just `</h1>`?  Also,  this doesn't seem to give you the answer you need to insert a button "after `item1Text`.  What do you mean by "after"?

Comment: Also ... there is a mistake in your HTML example.  Your ordered lists are malformed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you have some HTML "code" in a string, and you want to process it in Java.  I am assuming that you know where opening tag for the element is, and you want to insert the button after the closing tag.

The algorithm I am suggesting you only work if in each line has no more than one opening and closing element tag.  For example, it will not return a correct answer for:

```
 <p>
   <ol><li>item1Text</li><ol> // more than one opening and closing element tags
 </p>
```

My solution involves using a stack to match the start and end tags.  It assumes that you have already split the HTML into lines.

1. Set a counter to 1
2. Iterate the lines.  For each line:

   2.1. Check if you found a starting tag of an element ==> counter++,

   2.2. Check if this line also contains his closing tag ==> counter--1.

   2.3. Check if the counter value is 0, if it does you found the line where the element closes.  Otherwise, move to the next line .

In Java code, it will look something like this:

```
    if (line.matches("^(.*(<)(?!/).*)$")) {`
         counter++;
    }
    if (line.matches("^(.*(</).*)$")) {`
         counter--;
    }
    if(counter == 0) {
        // done searching for the closing tag
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> *is there any easy and efficient way to get last tags in any give HTML string*

You want to use a CSS query. However, you must either know the structure of the given HTML string or use a generic CSS query.

If you can add more information on the HTML string, some pointers may be provided.

---

Here is a CSS query example using the HTML fragment from your post.

```
li:contains(item1Text):last-of-type

li                    /* Select any LI element... */
:contains(item1Text)  /* containing 'item1Text' ... */
:last-of-type         /* and keep only the last LI. */
```

Here is below, an example Java code with the above CSS query.

**CODE**

```
String htmlFragment="<h1>\n <p>some text</p>\n<p>\n <ol>\n <li>item1Text</li>\n <ol>\n</p>\n</h1>";

System.out.println("BEFORE:\n" + htmlFragment);

Document parsedHtmlFragment = Jsoup.parse(htmlFragment);
Elements matchingLIs = parsedHtmlFragment.select("li:contains(item1Text):last-of-type");

for(Element matchingLI : matchingLIs) {
    // Append the button code at the end of the LI content.
    matchingLI.append("<button type=\"button\">BUTTON CONTENT HERE...</button>");
}

System.out.println("\nAFTER:\n" + parsedHtmlFragment.outerHtml());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
BEFORE:
<h1>
 <p>some text</p>
<p>
 <ol>
 <li>item1Text</li>
 <ol>
</p>
</h1>

AFTER:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <h1> <p>some text</p> <p> </p>
   <ol> 
    <li>item1Text<button type="button">BUTTON CONTENT HERE...</button></li> 
    <ol> 
     <p></p> 
    </ol>
   </ol></h1>
 </body>
</html>
```